# Pager.liveData method throws unresolved reference error

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-paging-3

While using the `Paging 3` library, I'm trying to return a `LiveData` object containing the `PagingData` from the `Repository` to the `ViewModel`. But the `Pager.liveData` method is throwing an unresolved reference error. Is the `.liveData` method deprecated in `Paging 3`? But, I sometimes see some YouTube tutorials use this method on the `Pager`. How else can I return a `LiveData` object on the `PagingData` from the `Pager`?

**Repository**

```
@Singleton
class ShoppingListItemsRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val shoppingListItemDao: ShoppingListItemDao,
    private val shoppingListItemMapper: ShoppingListItemMapper
) : ShoppingListItemsRepository {

    override fun getAllShoppingListItems(): LiveData<PagingData<ShoppingListItem>> {

        val pagingSourceFactory = { shoppingListItemDao.getAllShoppingListItems() }

        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 10,
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = pagingSourceFactory
        ).liveData.map { ... }
    }
}
```

Comment: So did you add `import androidx.paging.liveData`?

Comment: I already tried that and `import androidx.paging.*`. But, the problem went away after upgrading the paging library dependency version to 3.1.1. Thanks.